# Parsing a non json array...possible?

Tags: jackson

I need to parse an array made this way:

```
"rows":["row1","value"]
```

that one is not a json array, ofc, but isn't there a way to use the jackson deserializer in this case too?I really don't know why the authors decided to parse things like that but I have no choice...

edit:
How does it work. The authors decided that the first string in that array identifies the type of the second one. If the first is "atom", the second will be a string, an integer, and so on.
Example:

```
["atom","245"]
```

In case it is "array" the second will be a json array of some sort.

Example:

```
["array","[...]"]
```

In case it is "obj" it will be a json object

Example

```
["obj",{"hello":"world"}]
```

I would need a way to scan the first element and so change the field on the pojo which will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it between curly brackets which would make it a JSON object?

```
{
    "rows": ["row1", "value"]
}
```

If you want to convert that array into a dictionary, then please just ignore my answer...

Comment: problem is indeed the array. I'll add some clarifications to my question, wait a second